# Can FCM notification on Android overwrite previous one?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm using FCM to send notifications to Android devices. When the app is in background, if I send 10 notifications, the devices will show up 10 entries on the notification bar.

I want FCM to make only one entry on notification bar, i.e. the newer one will overwrite old ones. I don't find a key to set this at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream.

Is there a way to do, or it is impossible? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `tag`? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To achieve this,
in your notification payload, use the tag key

```
{
    "notification" : {
        "title" : "Notification Title",
        "body" : "Notification Body",
        "tag" : "your_unique_tag"
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible. Two approaches.

First is you make use of the `collapse_key` parameter to set the message as a *collapsible message*. Referring to the [FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages):

> A collapsible message is a message that may be replaced by a new message containing the same collapse key if it has yet to be delivered to the device.

It's actually included in the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream) you provided (first parameter under **Options**):

> **collapse_key** - This parameter identifies a group of messages (e.g., with collapse_key: "Updates Available") that can be collapsed, so that only the last message gets sent when delivery can be resumed. This is intended to avoid sending too many of the same messages when the device comes back online or becomes active.
>
> Note that there is no guarantee of the order in which messages get sent.
>
> Note: A maximum of 4 different collapse keys is allowed at any given time. This means a FCM connection server can simultaneously store 4 different send-to-sync messages per client app. If you exceed this number, there is no guarantee which 4 collapse keys the FCM connection server will keep.

---

Second approach is Notification bundling/stacking/grouping. As per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715021/4625829):

> By *grouping* the notification, I'm presuming you mean *stacking* or [bundling notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#bundle).
>
> This is more on how you handle the notification in your client app. You simply have to make use of the [setGroup()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroup(java.lang.String)) to add all your notifications to a single group then calling [notify()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html#notify(int,android.app.Notification)) to let the NotificationManager of the changes.
>
> This [Add Each Notification to a Group](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html#AddGroup) documentation pretty much sums it all up.

---

Update:

From one of the [linked posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43610964/4625829), using the [`tag`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-plain-text) parameter is also an option:

> Identifier used to replace existing notifications in the notification drawer.
>
> If not specified, each request creates a new notification.
>
> If specified and a notification with the same tag is already being shown, the new notification replaces the existing one in the notification drawer.

Comment: The first one I thought it was to avoid many notifications when device is "offline". If the device is online, notifications won't be grouped. I'll try second.

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai For the first one, yes. If you're aiming for the notifications to be consolidated, use the 2nd approach.

Comment: The 2nd approach seems to be usable only when app is in foreground. Can I do this when app is in background?

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai When the app is in background, depending on your payload structure, the notification will be [handled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) differently, sometimes, and as a default, when both notification and data are in the payload, the Notification will always be handled by Android's System Tray. One thing you could do is make sure to only use the data payload so that it will be handled in your `onMessageReceived()`.

Comment: Since iOS requires notification field, it's impossible to make notification compact or get any broadcast when receiving notifications right?

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai I think that is a different concern at hand and depends entirely on how you implement it by adjusting to the behavior of the devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124621/discussion-between-romulus-urakagi-tsai-and-al).

Comment: Can you please help me @AL. with **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085079/how-to-collapse-multiple-notifications-into-a-single-one-using-firebase/49089811)**?

Answer (score 0):

Use same id for the notification that will overwrite/update previous ones

```
notification:{
...
id:125,
..
}
```