# Parse-Server FCM: Show only one notification at a time

Tags: android, firebase, parse-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, parse-server

I am using Parse-Server cloud code to send FCM notifications to client.

However, I have not found a way to prevent notifications from stacking in my device's notification list.

The solution in a regular FCM setting is to set a tag.
[Android FCM - how to show only one notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610964/android-fcm-how-to-show-only-one-notification)
I tried setting `tag: "my_tag"` in my cloud code but it had no effect.

Does Parse-Server support the ability to only send one notification without previous ones from stacking on each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
{
  notification: {
    tag: 'my_tag'
  }
}
```