# Flutter: How to a schedule a notification that replaces the last scheduled notification

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, android-notifications

i am developing an app in which all notifications are schedule in advance. Each notification is set to a different time of the day and should replace the previous notification.

I.e 9.00 AM, 1.00 PM, 5.00 PM, Etc

I am using the package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications and the code below:

```
for (var interval in [1, 3, 4, 7, 7.5, 8]) {
      var time = (appStart).add(Duration(hours: interval));

       scheludeNotification(notifications,
                    title: "Title",
                    body: "Body"
                    time: time,
                    id: 0, // OR unique id
                    payload: '');
        
}

Future scheludeNotification(
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifications, {
  @required String title,
  @required String body,
  @required DateTime time,
  @required String payload,
  int id = 0,
}) =>
    _scheduleNotification(notifications,
        title: title,
        body: body,
        id: id,
        time: time,
        type: _ongoing,
        payload: payload);

Future _scheduleNotification(
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifications, {
  @required String title,
  @required String body,
  @required DateTime time,
  @required NotificationDetails type,
  @required String payload,
  int id = 0,
}) =>
    notifications.schedule(id, title, body, time, type, payload: payload);
```

Although the problem i am having is i want each new notification to replace the previous notification, if the user hasn't seen that notification yet. So the user isn't spammed with 20 new notifications when they return to their phone. If i use the same ID for each notification then it replaces the previous notification but since the notifications are all scheduled at the same time (i.e when the user first opens the app) rather than creating multiple scheduled notifications that replace their respective predecessor after being displayed. It just removes all the scheduled notifications and only schedules that last. If i use a unique id for each notification then it creates a new notification without removing the previous. I also cant use the `notifications.cancel(id);` function as the app might not be open when the user it notified.

Any ideas, Thanks.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this question? Many thanks!

Comment: If you are using fidebase cloud messaging, this is how you can achieve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782438/can-fcm-notification-on-android-overwrite-previous-one

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to track the notification ID and cancel them before scheduling their replacement. You can use `cancelAllNotifications()` or if you know the specific notification ID, use `cancelNotifiation()` and provide the ID.