# How to get the multiple notification as the group like whatsapp using FCM in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have tried below lines of code to get the multiple notification lilke whatsapp but did not get solution please check my code and let me know where am i doing wrong?
I am using the fcm to achieve this, please help me to short out from this problem

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setNumber(4);


            numMessages=numMessages+1;

            for (int i = 0; i <= numMessages; i++) {
                notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setNumber(numMessages);
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

            }
```

Please check the below image, in which i have showed that which type of group message i want to implement using `FCM`
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android FCM notification grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704562/android-fcm-notification-grouping)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing  [setGroup()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroup(java.lang.String)). This function is to add all your notifications to a single group (*grouped notification*).

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715021/4625829) for more details.

Comment: @AL: When I clicked on grouped message not able to navigate to relevant screen even when expand and click on single message then able to navigate to that screen. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about `InboxStyle` notifications. You can make it like:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
    .setContentText("Events received")
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
        new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
String[] events = new String[6];
// Sets a title for the Inbox in expanded layout
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");
...
// Moves events into the expanded layout
for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

    inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
}
// Moves the expanded layout object into the notification object.
mBuilder.setStyle(inBoxStyle);
...
// Issue the notification here.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Refer here for more details: [InboxStyle Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ApplyStyle)

Comment: i have used urs code..but it did not help me to get multiple message like whatsapp..Thanks for help..

Comment: Do u have another solution ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to confirm what exactly is your expectation?

Comment: That is exactly what InboxStyle notifications are for. The lines you'll be adding will be like "Sanjay-IT @ 8 idiots: Photo"