# Open Notification message from FCM as link/URL in Android Application if there is URL in the message of Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

PUSH Notification code using FCM sends title and message as notification text in Android and when i click on the Text, It takes me to the APP front page (in APP)
I am sending a URL as message in Notification so that someone clicks on the notification it "should open in app and open the appropriate page (as in the link) in app)

**Notification after FCM Push**

Title For Ex- The Climate Change impact

Message as URL For Ex - https://example.com/dsfdsfdsfdsf (pertinent to the URL which is dynamic)

I want to Open the URL in the APP instead of just opening the APP after clicking the URL. Kindly facilitate with the updated code

What changes should i do to achieve the same.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private TextView txtRegId, txtMessage;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    WebView webView;
    String url = "https://example.com";
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtRegId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_reg_id);
        txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_push_message);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // Make to run your application only in portrait mode
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); // Make to run your application only in LANDSCAPE mode


        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1212);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings browserSetting = webView.getSettings();
        browserSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browserSetting.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                textView.setText(progress + " %");

            }
        });

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // checking for type intent filter
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                    // gcm successfully registered
                    // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);



                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                    // new push notification is received

                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    txtMessage.setText(message);
                }
            }
        };

        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }



      // Fetches reg id from shared preferences
    // and displays on the screen
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // register GCM registration complete receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

        // register new push message receiver
        // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message arrives
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

        // clear the notification area when the app is opened
        NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

FirebaseMessageService

```
public class    MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
                } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had posted one answer before, you can check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/54321032/5611969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are not getting your message from Intent in MainActivity where your url is received.

Modify your activity onCreate method

```
       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtRegId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_reg_id);
    txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_push_message);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // Make to run your application only in portrait mode
    //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); // Make to run your application only in LANDSCAPE mode

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1212);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings browserSetting = webView.getSettings();
    browserSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browserSetting.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            textView.setText(progress + " %");
        }
    });

    mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                // gcm successfully registered
                // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received

                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                if (message != null) {
                    url = message;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                txtMessage.setText(message);
            }
        }
    };

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String yourUriThatYouWantToOpen = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    if (yourUriThatYouWantToOpen != null) {
        url = yourUriThatYouWantToOpen;
    }
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I am new to Android. Can you please tell me where to do the changes. I want to get the message (URL) from the notification and open in the app. Can you please provide it with example url etc,,

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters and if something still not clear then please ask again, if everything is clear then mark question as answered:)

Comment: Hello Sir, can you also tell me where to add the following, Will be immense help . Thanks for the assistance indeed its of a great help                                                                                                                 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_URI, yourUriThatYouWantToOpen);

Comment: Try only modify onCreate method like example above because first problem that I can see is that you are not loading received url. To do that you need get it from retrieved Intent with this line "intent.getStringExtra("message");"

Comment: Preliminary test- Works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another query- If the app is opened, i dont get the notification in the notification tray.. any remedy to this

Comment: remove this check "  if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {"

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, I understood certain concepts. Much Thanks. It is a privilege working with you. Thanks again

Comment: Hello Antonis, Just one question, While the app is open, and clicked on the notification, the appropriate link is not opened in the App. Any remedy for same

Comment: Hi Sir, anything that you can assist - While the app is open, and clicked on the notification, the appropriate link is not opened in the App. Any remedy for same

Comment: For this case I would recommend to use BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Thanks Antonis. God Bless.