# Is it possible to implement notification grouping/bundling using FCM in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to implement group notification like this [android group notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group) and [ios group notification](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/711/). But I can't able to do it. I tried this [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin too. but this works only when app open. not working on foreground(onResume) and background.

```
  void registerNotification() {
    
    _fcm.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
          return;
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
            return;
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
          return;
        },
        onBackgroundMessage: backgroundMessageHandler);
  }
```

**payload**

```
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: title,
    body: message,
  },
  data: {
    click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    sound: "default"
  },
  android: {
    priority: "high",
    collapse_key: userName,//tried to add collapse_key for group notification
  },
  apns: {
    headers: {
      "apns-priority": "5",
    },
  },
  token:token,
};
```

**SOLUTION**

I saw the react-native answer for this, you have to do same thing using Flutter with `firebase_messaging` [react native answer](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/449#issuecomment-404701979)

Comment: Hey. Got here from your comment. I'm not that familiar with flutter, but it would seem from the RN answer you linked that `.android.setGroup(ALERTS_GROUP)` exists -- I assume this is the one you're using? You mentioned that it only works when the app is open, its possible that this is basing from the payload content. I suggest trying sending a payload only with a `notification` and one only with `data` (keeping the other configs) and see if the behavior changes. Cheers!

Comment: Is it possible to create grouping notification using fcm payload? I saw this example. (groupKey is here) https://distriqt.github.io/ANE-PushNotifications/m.FCM-GCM%20Payload But there is no key(groupKey) on current fcm payload. isn't it?

Comment: There isn't a native `groupKey` in FCM. When you look at the sample, all of the items are inside `data` (i.e. `data: { notification: { ... } }`), meaning everything inside is a custom key-value -- which is also received and handled by the developer the way they want to.

Comment: okay @AL. I need to use group notification when the app on background (the app doesn't open). it means the app needs to run on background. isn't it? thanks again for support. sorry for my bad English

Comment: No worries. I don't know about flutter, but for Android you just need to extend the FirebaseMessagingService and it's usually expected to run in the background. After that, you would need to override the a function that triggers when a payload is received -- I did a quick scan of some pages and it seems the counterpart of it is the `backgroundMessageHandler`. From here, get the `data` and parse each and set the group as needed. That should pretty much do it. Good luck. Cheers!

Comment: @BloodLoss have you found solution?

Comment: @SardorbekRkh yes, I used custom notification for firebase messaging

Comment: @BloodLoss more details about that please

Comment: Hey @BloodLoss, can you please provide a flutter code sample to your solution? (I assume you have already integrated it on you app)

Comment: @Saifallak I wrote  platform-specific notifications to hanlde this.

Comment: Can you show sinppet of it, if possible

Answer (score -1):

If you want to submit a group, you need to subscribe to a topic, in the documentation that mentions it, you would no longer send a single token, but would instead subscribe to a topic and submit it to that topic.

Comment: are you sure? is it only support for the topic? okay, but how group notification works on like whatsapp/gmail?

Comment: I think you talk about the device group.

Comment: If I was referring to the device group, I think you need notifications to several people from the same chat

Comment: no no, if "A" user sent multiple messages to the "B" user. currently, there are lots of notifications came to in my notification panel, I want to group notification for that. (it's mean like above image like gmail/whatsapp). if "C" user sent multiple message to the "B user". I want to 2 groups..sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Topics are used for a group of wide scale sending to multiple uses. Basing from the question, @BloodLoss seems to be asking about bundling/grouping the notifications under one notification item, not a way to send them.